# Let's fill out the on-topic page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

I just VTC'd a recommendation question using custom text (the only other option was "price shopping" and it wasn't exactly that). The OP replied that they had checked the help pages and didn't see that asking for recommendations were off-topic here. I checked the help pages myself, and the [On Topic](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is empty!

The only site-specific line is:

> The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange is for people who love outdoor activities, excursions, and outdoorsmanship.

It does link to the [Don't Ask](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page, but that just contains more generic boilerplate about not asking subjective questions.

**This site has been around for a while! We should have a custom summary of what questions are considered on or off topic here.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site is about activities that occur in the Great Outdoors, including but not limited to:

- rock climbing
- fishing
- hiking
- mountaineering
- skiing
- backpacking
- caving
- etc.

Also on topic are questions about preparations for outdoor activities, questions about the necessary gear, or book recommendations. **Recommendations for what item to purchase are off-topic;** questions about what features one should look for are on-topic.

The full list of topics that have been declared on-topic can be found [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/list-of-everything-that-has-been-declared-on-or-off-topic-on-the-great-outdoors).

Answer (score 2):

The page has already been filled out, which is a great step forward! The community wiki from which it came is now status-completed. Therefore, I'll add another answer.

While all of those are excellent examples, I think our community is broad enough that adding some more topics on that page is a good idea. There are things we do here that people don't know about, and I'd like to suggest a few that are popular. Please feel free to add more if you'd like!

- Boating
- Camping
- Bird and animal watching and behavior