# Synonyms of the Scope/Off Topic/On Topic/Topics tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

When looking at the this [question](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/lets-fill-out-the-on-topic-page), I wanted to see what topics had recently been decided were on or off topic. I noticed that there were two tags [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) and [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and they were used rather inconsistently.

For example a question would be "Is this on topic" and be tagged with [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) or vice versa. There were even questions with both tags used.

As neither of the tags had usage guidance, I simplified both down to a single tag [off-or-on-topic](/questions/tagged/off-or-on-topic) and added [usage guidance](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/off-or-on-topic/info)

> Questions about whether particular topics are off or on topic.

However there is also the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)

> Use this tag when examining what is on-topic or off-topic, and why.

and there is the [topics](/questions/tagged/topics) which has no usage guidance but is used in much the same way.

Can we make [off-or-on-topic](/questions/tagged/off-or-on-topic) and [topics](/questions/tagged/topics)  a synonym of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)?

Comment: It's not *as* big an issue on meta, but please don't just go and make such a large quantity of edits all at once. A merge would have gotten rid of the redundant tags without bumping every question that used them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've merged the tags and set up a synonym [off-or-on-topic](/questions/tagged/off-or-on-topic) -> [scope](/questions/tagged/scope). The individual [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) tags will be automatically deleted in about 24 hours, and I don't expect them to come back, but if they do just point it out and a mod will set up those synonyms too.